# How to prevent a form in Access from deleting data from other tables used to filter in the data source query

Tags: ms-access

I am new to MS Access and VBA coding, and what I know I had to teach myself through video tutorials and reading up on the web. I have an input Form which which gets its data from a query. The query itself gets its information from a table and another query. The reason is that the other query is what filters the data so that the current user can only see his/ her own records, and not that of others. It has been designed in such a way that if a subordinate changes from supervisor, one merely have to update the supervisor name, and all the prior data in the table for that subordinate will also then reflect for the new supervisor, and no longer the old supervisor.

The problem is that the delete button on the input Form (which was created with the button wizard) not only delete the record from the table, but also from the table used to filter the subordinates. I only want it to delete the record from the actual table used in the data source query.

How would I go about to stop it from deleting in both tables?

I have attached a snapshot of a portion of the data source query, just so that you can understand what is meant by the above. The delete button on the input Form deletes the data from the table named "TableReviewNotes" and "TableAuditorNames". It should only delete the record from "TableReviewNotes".

Thanks in advance.
[image: Data Source Query]

Comment: Edit question to show tables as text tables, not image. Do tables have Cascade Delete enforced? By "**table** used to filter subordinates" do you mean a query?

Comment: Hi PEH. You mentioned something which I definitely did not know, and which is cascade delete. I have now read up on this, and it is exactly what I needed to resolve my problem. Many, many thanks.